# How to approach leaving a company within 3 months?

Tags: professionalism, career-development, ethics, quitting, education

I joined a startup almost 2 months back. Before this I was a partner in another startup where I worked for around 4-5 months but things didn't work out for me there and I started hunting for a job. Along with the job hunt I also started to apply for MS programs in a couple of universities but I was already late and I thought the chances of getting in were bleak. Meanwhile I got the offer from my current company. A bit about this company-

It is a two year old startup which has recently raised decent funding, I was the 13th employee and there are total 18 employees now. It was started by some very senior people from a blue chip company where I worked for around 4 years (last to last company) and therefore gave me a slight advantage while selecting me as we all came from the same background. They have given me quite a handsome compensation and are investing a lot of resources in me as well.

Now last week I got admitted to two Universities where I had applied. Now I am in a conundrum for what to do as I am pretty happy with the work but at the same time I want to go for my MS as its a goal for which I have been working towards for a long time. I want to resign but I don't want to create complications with the people. Also can it create difficulties for me since I left my last company also in 5 months and will leaving this too in 3-4 months.

How would you approach this?

Comment: Is it about not hurting company and it's projects? Or about your career? What complications you are afraid of?

Comment: About the relationship with the folks(founder and cofounders). They are nice people and we have worked together in the past in my last to last company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talk to your boss as soon as you can, explain your reasons etc,. That is the only way to minimise the impact of your quitting. Give as much notice as you can and document all your work professionally.

In answer to your other question 'Can it create difficulties for you in the future'

Yes it can, it looks like job hopping, but it's mitigated by the fact that you left to pursue your education which is understandable, so the difficulties are not that great.

Comment: Unfortunately, as someone on here once said to my question and I paraphrase "I wouldn't even look twice at a resume/cv with alot of jobs listed in a short space of time, never mind to ask about the circumstances surrounding the reasons."

Comment: @Dansmith 2 isn't a lot, previously he did 4 years, it's not a pattern

Comment: I know, I was only adding some further information to your comment about "job hopping"

Comment: How prudent will it be for me to not list these 3 months in my CV.

Comment: That's a judgement call, if you got a good reference from there I would definitely list it with the implication that it was a temporary position to make money before going to school..